# Cloudera Impala ODBC driver for Windows - (Error 1170) Unexpected response received from server

Tags: odbc, cloudera, impala

I'm new to Big Data, especially Cloudera and Impala. I have been asked to setup an ODBC driver on my Windows laptop so that I can later connect my C# console app to Hadoop.

These are the steps I have already taken:

1. Installed ClouderaImpalaODBC32.msi driver
2. Received an SSL Certificate file from DBAs.
3. Created a new OBDC connection in "ODBC Data Source Administrator (32-bit)" tool in Windows
4. My ODBC connection uses .com Host, port 21050, DB name, username and SSL Certificate.

But when I click [TEST] button, I get the following error:

> FAILED! [Cloudera][DriverSupport] (1170) Unexpected response received from server. Please ensure the server host and port specified for the connection are correct.

Can someone please help me find resolution to my problem?

Thanks!